# CryptoJS passphrase, salt, and iv does not matter?

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I'm trying to understand how to use the AES of CryptoJS to encrypt some data. I made a simple HTML page with JavaScript to see CryptoJS AES in action.

At first I thought encryption/decryption was working perfectly. But then I tried to change the passphrase, salt, and IV. I found out that, given the same message, the resulting ciphertext is identical no matter how I change the passphrase, salt, and IV.

I downloaded `aes.js` and `pbkdf2.js` from v3.1.2 of https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/downloads and referred to https://github.com/mpetersen/aes-example

Here is my HTML in its entirety (since it is a really simple page I think it's okay to post the entire thing)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>Decryptor</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="inputElement" />
    <button id="decrypt">Decrypt!</button>
    <br />
    <p id="ciphertext">
        Ciphertext
    </p>
    <p id="plaintext">
        Plaintext
    </p>
</body>

<script src="aes.js"></script>
<script src="pbkdf2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function decrypt() {
        var input = document.getElementById("inputElement").value;
        var ciphertextElement = document.getElementById("ciphertext");
        var plaintextElement = document.getElementById("plaintext");

        var message = input;
        var passphrase = "myPassphrase";
        var salt = "mySalt";
        var iv = "myIV";

        var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(
            passphrase,
            CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(salt),
            { keySize: this.keySize, iterations: this.iterationCount }
        );

        var parsedIV = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv);

        var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
            message,
            key,
            { iv: parsedIV }
        );

        var ciphertext = encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
        ciphertextElement.innerHTML = ciphertext;

        var cipherParams = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create(
            { ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(ciphertext) }
        );
        var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
            cipherParams,
            key,
            { iv: parsedIV }
        );

        var plaintext = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
        plaintextElement.innerHTML = plaintext;
    }

   var decryptionButton = document.getElementById("decrypt");
    decryptionButton.onclick = decrypt;
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: `"myIV"` is not hex, why parse it as such? that could result in null, which would be the same always...

Comment: dandavis is correct, but the real issue is that `this.keySize` is null. So, the `key` will always be the same regardless of parameters. You have to use the `new` keyword to use `this`

Comment: Thank you @dandavis and @artjom-b! I parsed the salt and iv with Utf8 and also changed keysize and iterations to not use `this`. Now when I change the values the ciphertext also changes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the advice from @dandavis and @artjom-b.

Because my salt and iv are string, I parse them with Utf8:

```
CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(salt);
CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv);
```

And for key generation, I use static values:

```
        var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(
        passphrase,
        CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(salt),
        { keySize: 512/32, iterations: 1000 }
    );
```

And now the ciphertext changes as I change the passphrase, salt, and iv values.